What ingredient(s) create the savory finish in Palestinian dukkah?
Middle Eastern friends introduced me to Palestinian-style dukkah, which is based on wheat berries rather than on the nuts used in Egyptian-style dukkah. While some of the recipes I've tried at home get close, none achieves the long, savory finish of the first dukkah I tasted. In fact, the label for that product clearly does not identify all of the ingredients, as I can taste a tangy flavor that is not represented by any of the listed ingredients.
Wondering if a particular sea salt might be the champion and, after reading other salt-spice-umami posts on this forum, I see that there are "sea salt" products on the market which add porcini, black garlic, kelp or "vegetable extract."
I'm hoping a reader familiar with Palestinian cuisine can get me over the flavor finish line.

what were the ingredients listed for the original product?

Tangy is usually used in the sense of sour/acidic - is this what you are tasting? If so, it might be sumac or lemon salt. Can you please add the ingredients list for the product and a list for the recipe you tried.

Original product ingredients: wheat, sesame, salt, anise, cumin. I agree that the tangy flavor comes from sumac berry and/or citric acid, neither of which is listed as an ingredient. Also, the color is much more red than my home-made attempts, which I have approached by adding Aleppo pepper flakes. Because anise is listed before cumin, anise flavor should be pronounced, but the cumin flavor is much more evident.

Are you certain it's umami that you're missing? Supermarket spices are frequently low-quality and have a bland, washed-out taste, similar to supermarket fruit and vegetables. If the original is made with well-grown spices and yours isn't, the original will certainly have a stronger and richer flavor.

Thanks for the suggestion... I learned, long ago, that supermarket spices are higher priced and lower quality than every other source. I buy spices from local ethnic markets and, in a pinch (get it, spices, in a "pinch?") online.

After more research and testing, I believe the answer is: ground, toasted caraway seed. In addition to enhancing the salty character of the spice mixture, it gives all of the flavors a longer finish on the palate. This result surprises me because the caraway flavor is so different from the un-toasted caraway used in seeded rye bread or some northeastern Indian dishes.
My DIY version is, now, acceptably close to the original I enjoyed so much.

I wonder if there's a translation error there - caraway is quite similar in appearance to cumin and is even called "Persian cumin" sometimes. With both anise and caraway I would expect a strongish flavour of anise in there, which makes me think it might be some sort of error on the translators' part

I have encountered this problem with other spice blends, e.g., za'atar referring to thyme as oregano. In this case, I suspect caraway may have been translated as anise, as there's nearly no anise flavor but the cumin flavor and aroma are pronounced.
